# The Phrase "off-cycle internship experience" in CV

Tags: meaning

While looking over some example templates of CV, had bumped over a phrase "off-cycle internship" under Work experience slot.

Any idea what does it mean?

"off-cycle" is not listed in Wiktionary but it would be in another dictionary.

Anyway, for clarification of its conventional use of meaning

I need your help and references.

Comment: Ask those who wrote those CVs.

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.wallstreetoasis.com/forums/so-what-exactly-do-they-mean-by-off-cycle-internship

***Off-cycle internships*** are internships that take place outside the regular cycle of when internships normally take place. Since most internships take place during the summer, an off-cycle internship would be one that takes place outside of the summer. They usually are just as worthwhile as "regular" internships, but are often times a bit more laid back.